# Function to split value between columns in access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have the following table:

[image: Current]

And I need to split the value column into two columns based on the value of the status column, also add a difference between the two. Like This:

[image: Example]

I was able to split it by using two separate queries, but when I merge them together I get duplicate values, even If I use the Sum and group by the costumer.

Comment: Its preferable to add the data over here rather then an image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sue conditional aggregation:

```
select customer, 
       sum(iif(status = 'debt', value, 0)) as debt,
       sum(iif(status = 'pay', value, 0)) as pay
       (sum(iif(status = 'debt', value, 0)) -
        sum(iif(status = 'pay', value, 0))
       ) as diff
from t
group by customer;
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you all for the responses!

Answer (score 1):

Try this please

```
    tb1: Customer, value, status

select d.Customer, d.value as debt, IIf(p.value Is Null, 0, p.value) as pay, d.value - IIf(p.value Is Null, 0, p.value)  as diff
from 
(select Customer, value from tb1 where status  = 'debt')d
left join
(select Customer, value from tb1 where status  = 'pay')p on d.Customer = p.Customer
```

Answer (score 1):

With a LEFT self join:

```
select t.Customer,
  t.[value] as debt, tt.[value] as pay, t.[value] - Nz(tt.[value]) as diff
from tablename t left join tablename tt
on tt.customer = t.customer and t.[status] <> tt.[status]
where t.[status] = 'debt'
```

Results:

```
Customer    debt    pay   diff
Fernando    445     445   0
Marcelo     332     123   209
Adriana     889           889
```